# Where I should setup the PATH so psql command can work?

Tags: postgresql, macos, command-line, zsh

I am using a mac and when i use psql in terminal i got zsh: command not found: psql
I searched and saw that i should set up the PATH  `export PATH=${POSTGRES_HOME}/bin:${PATH}` so my question where i do this ? and what are the variables between { }.

Answer (score 0):

I missed this :

sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d &&
echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it's your decision where to do it. I suggest that you read first the section "STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES" in the *zsh man page* to see what files are processed by zsh on start and on this choose the one which is best for you.

For instance, If you want the setting it for **every** zsh (interactive and non-interactive, login and non-login) shells, your ~/.zshenv would be the place to go. If you want it for any interactive shell only, put it into ~/.zshrc.

In any case, I suggest that you add the command

```
typeset -aU path
```

This avoids that the same directory will be added again and again by each zsh child process.

Finally, you may find it more convenient to use `path` instead of `PATH`:

```
path+=($POSTGRES_HOME/bin)
```

Since the scalar `PATH` is tied to the array `path`, you can use either one.

Comment: @jj-ammar : In case that this solves your problem, please consider accepting my answer.